# Django | No existe la columna consumible_consumible

Tags: django, django-models

Desde que he colocado en el modelo (en la clase class Consumible(models.Model)) la columna "**imagen_consumible**" me devuelve error. Si lo dejo comentado, no devuelve error(claro que esa información no se ve al comentarlo):

Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Archivo** models.py

```
class ImagenConsumible(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField('Nombre',max_length=50)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='consumibles/')            
              
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
    
class Consumible(models.Model):                 
        marca = models.CharField('Marca',max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
        modelo = models.CharField('Modelo',max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
        cons_numserie = models.CharField('NºSerie',max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
        disp_padre = models.ForeignKey(Dispositivo, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
        fecha_colocacion = models.DateTimeField ('FechaColocacion',null=True, blank=True)
        imagen_consumible = models.ForeignKey(ImagenConsumible, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=False, blank=True)        
    
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.cons_numserie)
```

**Archivo** admin.py

```
class ImagenConsumibleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'name',
    )
admin.site.register(Consumible,ImagenConsumibleAdmin)

class ConsumibleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'tipo_consumible',
        'marca',
        'modelo',
        'cons_numserie',
        'disp_padre',
        'imagen_consumible',
        'fecha_colocacion',
    )
admin.site.register(Consumible,ConsumibleAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola esto parece un error de la base de datos. es como si el makemigratios y migrate estuvieran mal ejecutados o un error al hacer las migraciones. Habria que ver si hay algun error en views .py o url.py hacia la ruta consumible.Lo he probado en el panel admin y no da ningun tipo de error dejando agregar imagen consumible.prueba a borrar imagen_consumible y aplicar todas migraciones y volver a incluirlo.

Comment: Es curioso, he borrado datos existentes. He quitado la classe ImagenConsumible y todo lo que hace referencia a él. He migrado. Después he activado de nuevo la clase ImagenConsumible, etc. Migro y todo bien hasta que añado un nuevo elemento que contiene una imagen y salta el error. Un error parecido: "ProgrammingError at /admin/consumible/consumible/add/

no existe la columna «imagen_consumible_id» en la relación «consumible_consumible»
LINE 1: ...s_numserie", "disp_padre_id", "fecha_colocacion", "imagen_co..."

Answer (score 0):

```
python manage.py makemigrations 
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Eso ya se ha hecho, incluso varias veces. Pero el error no está ahí. Gracias teury diaz, muy amable.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no estoy seguro de que sea esto, creo que el error es que en el admin.py en vez de poner:

```
admin.site.register(Consumible,ImagenConsumibleAdmin)
```

hay que poner:

```
admin.site.register(ImagenConsumible,ImagenConsumibleAdmin)
```

Corrigiendo esto, funciona perfecto.